# What resources are available to identify oral medication?

Tags: medications, pill

What databases are available to visually identify oral medication found without packaging?  Are there different databases for US, European, Far East, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several "pill identifiers" available online:

- [RxList](https://www.rxlist.com/pill-identification-tool/article.htm)
- [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/pill-identification/default.htm)
- [Drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/pill_identification.html) (international database from 185 countries)

You enter the shape and color of a pill and any imprints and you get the pictures with drug names.

There are apps for mobile phones:

- [ID My Pill](http://www.idmypill.com/)

  You take a photo of a pill and you get the info.

Or you go to a search engine and type "recognize my pill" in or so.

[ResourcePharm.com](http://www.resourcepharm.com/pharmacist/identification-of-foreign-medicines.html) has a page: "Identify Foreign Medicines" with links to lists of drugs in various countries.

Comment: Do these catalog non-US medications?

Comment: For which area do you need to know? All non-US areas, Europe or something more specific?

Comment: Western Europe, Central Europe, and Russia would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Try them. Drugs.com also has a forum, where you can get answers from the staff, I believe https://www.drugs.com/forum/pill-identification/ .

Comment: Drugs.com has an international database; probably the biggest available.

Comment: Regarding the part of "go to a search engine and type "recognize my pill" in or so", since Google indexes most of the images found at the mentioned databases, searching Google for the **imprint** (letters and numbers debossed\printed on the tablet\capsule) serves as a convenient shortcut in most cases.